# NullPointer exception while sending email through javamail

Tags: jsp, maven, tomcat, servlets, jakarta-mail

I have a servlet code to send email using javamail. Everything looks fine, but NullPointerException was thrown when calling my send() method. Below are my code.

Servlet:

```
package com.lsp.web;

import com.lsp.service.Mailer;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

@WebServlet(name = "contact", urlPatterns = {"/contact"})
public class ContactServlet extends SpringInjectedServlet {
@EJB
private Mailer emailBean;

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    req.getRequestDispatcher("contact.jsp").forward(req, resp);
}

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String customerEmail = req.getParameter("email");
    String subject = req.getParameter("subject");
    String body = req.getParameter("message");

    String error = null;
    String succMess = null;

    try {
        javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress ia = new javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress(customerEmail);
        ia.validate();
        emailBean.send(customerEmail, subject, body); //HERE I CALL MAILER.SEND() METHOD WHERE NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION CAME FROM
        req.setAttribute("succMessage", succMess);
        req.getRequestDispatcher("sent.jsp").forward(req, resp);

    } catch (javax.mail.internet.AddressException ae) {
        error = "您指出的邮箱地址不存在";
        req.setAttribute("errorMessage", error);
        req.getRequestDispatcher("contact.jsp").forward(req, resp);
    }
    catch (MessagingException mex) {
        error = "发送失败";
        req.setAttribute("errorMessage", error);
        req.getRequestDispatcher("contact.jsp").forward(req, resp);
    }
}
}
```

Then I call Mailer class to send a mail:

```
package com.lsp.service;

import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import java.util.Properties;

public class Mailer {
public void send(String from, String subject, String body) {
    String to = "jshao745@gmail.com";
    String host = "localhost";

    Properties properties = System.getProperties();
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);

    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

    try{
        // Create a default MimeMessage object.
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

        // Set From: header field of the header.
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

        // Set To: header field of the header.
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));

        // Set Subject: header field
        message.setSubject(subject);

        // Send the actual HTML message, as big as you like
        message.setSubject(body);

        // Send message
        Transport.send(message);
        System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");
    }catch (MessagingException mex) {
        mex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

My JSP submit form:

```
<form action="contact" method="post">
<p>Your email address: <input name="email"></p>
<p>Mail subject: <input name="subject"></p>
<p>Mail message: <textarea name="message"></textarea></p>
<p><input type="submit"><span class="message"></span></p>
</form>
```

When I type all the information and click the submit button, I got `NullPointerException` at a line in `ContactServlet` where calling `send()` method in Mailer class (I put a comment with all cap words).

I cannot find out what I did wrong.

I appreciate if someone could help me.

Comment: Provide stack trace and line numbers, please.

Comment: Can you show the stacktrace? at least some of it.

Comment: This line looks suspicous: `message.setSubject(body)`. I guess you wanted to set the body instead.

Comment: Yes, it was a typo. Thank you.

Comment: Have you defined your Mailer class as a EJB? Since you have to annotate it with either (@)Stateless or (@)Stateful in order to reference it from your ContactServlet using (@)EJB

Comment: Not yet, but could you please tell me the difference?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest instead of using

```
message.setBody(body);
```

you first wrap the body in a DataHandler:

```
DataHandler messageDataHandler = new DataHandler(body, "text/plain; charset=\"UTF-8\"");
message.setDataHandler(messageDataHandler);
```

Comment: I don't know why this works but I've been stuck forever on this, and this answer fixed it. Thanks!